# Obtain the Count per Month from the Count per Day using Java Streams and groupingBy()

Tags: java, datetime, hashmap, java-stream

I want to transform a list with *per-day* sales (whatever, doesn't matter) into a list of *per-month* sales.

So I have a `List<Map<String, Object>>` `perDay`, which contains these daily values:

```
[{DATE=2022-01-01, COUNT=5}, {DATE=2022-01-02, COUNT=3}, {DATE=2022-02-29, COUNT=4}]
```

These values should be gathered into monthly values, like that:

```
[{DATE=2022-01, COUNT=8}, {DATE=2022-02, COUNT=4}]
```

I want to use `groupingBy()` method with streams.

Here's my code:

```
    Map<String, Object> jan1 = new HashMap<>();
    jan1.put("DATE", "2022-01-01"); jan1.put("COUNT", "5");
    Map<String, Object> jan2 = new HashMap<>();
    jan2.put("DATE", "2022-01-02"); jan2.put("COUNT", "3");
    Map<String, Object> feb1 = new HashMap<>();
    feb1.put("DATE", "2022-02-29"); feb1.put("COUNT", "4");
    List<Map<String, Object>> perDay = List.of(jan1, jan2, feb1);

Map<String, Object> perMonth = perDay.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy("???", 
                    Collectors.summingInt(f -> Integer.parseInt((String) f))));
```

I guess, I'm close, but I'm not quite there yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that your dates are always in format

```
2022-01-01
```

You could try:

```
 var map = perDay.stream().collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(monthMap -> ((String) monthMap.get("DATE")).substring(0, 7),
                  Collectors.summingInt(monthMap -> Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(monthMap.get("COUNT"))))));
```

Returns:

```
{2022-01=8, 2022-02=4}
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach you've introduced is not maintainable and as a consequence prone to errors and code duplications, and also makes extension of the code harder.

These are the main issues:

- Don't use `Object` as a generic type. Because a collection element of type `Object` worth nothing without casting. If you have no intention to write muddy code full of casts and `intanceof` checks, don't take this rode.
- `Map` - is **not** the same thing as JSON-object (*I'm not talking about classes from Java-libraries like Gson, they are map-based*), don't confuse a *way of structuring the human-readable text* with the implementation of the ***data structure***.
- Keys like `"DATE"` and `"COUNT"` are useless - you can simply store the actual **date** and **count** instead.
- Using `String` as a type for numbers and dates doesn't give you any advantage. There's nothing you can do with them (*apart from comparing and printing on the console*) without parsing, almost like with `Object`. Use an appropriate data type for every element. Why? Because `LocalDate`, `Integer`, `YearMonth` have their own unique behavior that `String` can't offer you.

That's how you can improve your code by tuning the collection representing *sales per day* `List<Map<String, Object>>` into a `Map<LocalDate, Integer>` which is way more handy:

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer> salesPerDay = perDay.stream()
    .map(map -> Map.entry(LocalDate.parse((String) map.get("DATE"), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE),
                          Integer.parseInt((String) map.get("COUNT"))))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

And that's how you can produce a map containing *sales per month* from it ([`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) from the `java.time` package is used as a *key*):

```
Map<YearMonth, Integer> salesPerMonth = salesPerDay.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                entry -> YearMonth.from(entry.getKey()),
                Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));

salesPerMonth.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
2022-01 -> 8
2022-02 -> 4
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rE1)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend against using a list of maps either for date sales, or for month sales.

Here is your data.

```
Map<String, Object> jan1 = new HashMap<>();
jan1.put("DATE", "2022-01-01");
jan1.put("COUNT", "5");
Map<String, Object> jan2 = new HashMap<>();
jan2.put("DATE", "2022-01-02");
jan2.put("COUNT", "3");
Map<String, Object> feb1 = new HashMap<>();
feb1.put("DATE", "2022-02-29");
feb1.put("COUNT", "4");
List<Map<String, Object>> perDay = List.of(jan1, jan2, feb1);
```

And here is how you would do it.

- stream the maps
- take the date and use only the year/month part
- convert the count to an integer (so it can be summed)
- and when duplicate keys are encountered, add the counts
- note that this involves casting of values.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = perDay.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                mp -> ((String) mp.get("DATE")).substring(0,
                        7),
                mp -> Integer
                        .valueOf((String) mp.get("COUNT")),
                Integer::sum));
```

But your initial `List<Map<String,Object>>` doesn't let you choose the date since there is no relationship to the DATE value of the map to the index of the list.  However, if you stored them as a `Map<String,Integer>`, you could then retrieve the count for any DATE using the consistent format of `yyyy-MM-dd`.  And the process would need no casts to work.

```
Map<String, Integer> perDay = new HashMap<>();
perDay.put("2022-01-01", 5);
perDay.put("2022-01-02", 3);
perDay.put("2022-02-29", 4);
```

This also makes it easier to convert to the month total sales as follows:

- stream the `entrySets` for `perDay`
- convert to a `Map<String,Integer>` for month and sales. Use substring to get just the year and month portion via `Entry.getKey()`. Note: this works only if your date format is consistent.
- get the count from `Entry::getValue` using a method reference.
- and for duplicate counts (same month, different days) sum them using Integer::sum

```
Map<String, Integer> monthSales = daySales.entrySet()
        .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey().substring(0,7),
                             Entry::getValue,
                             Integer::sum));

monthSales.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
2022-01=8
2022-02=4
```

And like before, you can get the monthly counts for any `yyyy-MM` key if it exists.

Suggestions:

- first and foremost, don't use `Object`.  Use a specific type, in your case Integer for the value.  Otherwise you will have to do casting which can lead to errors.
- Consider using a class to Store related information.  A sales class could be used to store the Date and count as well as other information.

  ```
   class Sales {
       private int count; 
       private String date;
       // getters
       // toString
  }
  ```
- For handling dates, look at the classes in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.